# Java code to find difference between two time,where time is stored in date type and time is in 24 hour format

Tags: java, time, datetime-format

i need java code to find difference between two times in 24 hour format 
for example:
20:00:00 - 04:00:00

and the expected output is 8 hrs
but now output is 16 hrs
when i tried 12 hour format out put is coming 4.

below is the code used to parse  and to find difference

```
SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date d1 = readFormat.parse(txtshiftIn);
Date d2 = readFormat.parse(txtshiftOut);
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
```

input is just 20:00 and 04:00 no seconds and AM/PM part.

Comment: @Govinda Sakhare String txtshiftIn=request.getParameter("shiftIn");

Comment: So the times expand two different days and it is not part of the same day?

Comment: yes,time expands two different days,its not part of the same day

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with using `Date` is it still expects an actual date even though you are using just the time portion of it, so if you're just sending it the time it will not be correct.

Instead use `LocalTime` and `ChronoUnit.HOURS` to get the difference between the time.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse(txtshiftIn, dtf);
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse(txtshiftOut, dtf);

long diff = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(lt1, lt2);
```

This will show `-16` which means that `lt1` is ahead of `lt2` which indicates `lt2` is the next day so we can modify it to get the differences as such

```
if (diff < 0) {
  diff += 24;
}
```

This will give you the `8` hour difference you're expecting.

**UPDATE**
To account the difference in minutes you can do the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse(txtshiftIn, dtf);
LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse(txtshiftOut, dtf);

long diff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(lt1, lt2); //get diff in minutes

if (lt2.isBefore(lt1)) {
  diff += TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1); //add a day to account for day diff
}

long hours = diff / 60;
long minutes = diff % 60;

LocalTime newTime = LocalTime.parse(String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes), dtf); //Format the difference to be converted to LocalTime

System.out.println(newTime);
```

This will produce the difference in minutes:

`08:30`

**Update 2**

Here is a cleaner method that returns a `Duration`

```
public Duration timeDifference(String txtshiftIn, String txtshiftOut) {
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
  LocalTime lt1 = LocalTime.parse(txtshiftIn, dtf);
  LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse(txtshiftOut, dtf);

  Duration between = Duration.between(lt1, lt2);

  if (lt2.isBefore(lt1)) { //account for lt2 being on the next day
    between = Duration.ofMinutes(TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1)).plus(between);
  }

  return between;
}
```

Comment: expected output is 8,but the output of above code is -16

Comment: Fixed answer to accommodate the difference in days.

Comment: Great. You can use `lt2.isBefore(lt1)` to improve readibility

Comment: You can even parse without the formatter, just `LocalTime.parse(txtshiftIn)` and the same for the shift out time.

Comment: but when i executed the code to find time between 20:00 and 4:30 it is giving 9 hrs,the expected output is 8 hrs 30 minutes

Comment: Because its rounding. If you change `ChronoUnit.HOURS` to `ChronoUnits.MINUTES` itll return the minutes between then you can do the conversion on how many hours and minutes it is

Comment: i tried but i am not able to obtain the expected output as 8 hrs 30 min .can you please provide the code to convert to hours and minutes after finding difference

Comment: See my edit. It returns a `LocalTime` now so it will be hours and minutes

Comment: Using a `LocalTime` for an amount of time is wrong. You should use `Duration`. It will also be simpler. I have retracted my upvote.

Comment: @OleV.V.You're correct `Duration` is the simplest way to do it and that would be what I would do. I was thinking of more what the OP wanted. I updated my answer to include the Duration

Answer (score 1):

While it is strongly recommended you use a more up-to-date Java time library like LocalTime your logic so far actually is correct with one little caveat:

```
SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date d1 = readFormat.parse(txtshiftIn);
Date d2 = readFormat.parse(txtshiftOut);
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
```

In your code if d1 is after d2 you will get a negativ result for `long diff`

So when you say

> "but now output is 16 hrs"

The actual output is **-16 hrs**

Of course minus sixteen hours doesn't make much sense in your case, but you can easily fix that with the simple trick of just adding 24 hours in case of a negative result for diff. (And -16+24 is the 8 you expected as a result).

So just add the following lines at the end of your posted code

```
if(diff < 0) {
    diff = 86400000 + diff;
}
```

And you will get the results you expect!
(86400000 is the 24h expressed in milliseconds)